# Create INSERT INTO statement passing a variable list like list of the column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this little statement to extract the list of the column of a table:

```
DECLARE @j INT = 1
DECLARE @verifyColumn INT = @pkcounter --it count the number of column of the table
WHILE @j <> @verifyColumn +1
    BEGIN
        set @multipleColumn = @multipleColumn+ (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema_name AND TABLE_NAME = @table_source AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @k) + ','
        SET @j = @j + 1
        set @k = @k + 1
        SET @pkcounter = @pkcounter - 1;
    END

PRINT 'multipleColumn: ' + @multipleColumn
```

Now i need to use the variable with the list of the column in an insert statement, a sort of:

```
INSERT INTO table_name_target (@multipleColumn) SELECT a,b FROM table_name_source
```

It's possible to do that?
Thank you all

Comment: Not like this, unfortunately. You'll have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Your `SELECT` only contains 2 columns, so what do you want to happen when more/less than 2 columns are returned for the column list? Is it intentional that it'll error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you must use sp_executesql. Like this:

```
DECLARE @multipleColumn VARCHAR(1000) = NULL, -- Must be null
    @schema_name NVARCHAR(128)='dbo',
    @table_source NVARCHAR(128)='<src>',
    @table_target NVARCHAR(128)='<dest>',
    @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @multipleColumn = COALESCE(@multipleColumn+', ', '') + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
WHERE
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema_name
    AND c.TABLE_NAME = @table_source;

SET @stmt=CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', QUOTENAME(@table_target),' (', @multipleColumn, ')
SELECT ', @multipleColumn, ' FROM ', QUOTENAME(@table_source), ';');

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt;
```

And, as always, be careful of [sql injection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/raulga/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection/) when using sp_executesql!

Comment: As you know Injection is a concern, why haven't you used `QUOTENAME`?

Comment: It's not `sp_executesql` that is open to injection either, it's concatenating strings and not sanitising the values that is the injection problem. something like `EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT 1 AS One;';` can never suffer injection. The key way to ensure that when using dynamic SQL is to quote your objects, and parametrise values wherever possible.

Comment: True! I should have added QUOTENAME(). I've changed that now!